# Test case failure due to static mocks

Tags: java, jacoco, java-17

we have recently upgraded our project to java 17, we have integration tests in the application.

Earlier we used jacocoVersion = '0.8.4', with this version no test case are running on sonar, so we upgraded jacocoVersion = '0.8.8' (as compatible with java 17), now test cases are failing saying
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Because we were using static mocks in tests, so we are trying to remove static mocks,
here is the code

```
@Service
public final class TestedClass{

    private Resource resource;

    @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
      resource = ServiceFactory.getResource(env);
    }
    }
}

public class ServiceFactory {

  private static Resource resource;

  public static Resource getResource(String env) {
    if (resource == null) {
      resource = new Resource(env);
    }
    return resource;
  }
}
```

And this is the base of a test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestedClassTest{

    @Autowired
    private TestedClass instance;
    
    private Resource resource = Mockito.mock(Resource.class);
    private MockedStatic<ServiceFactory> serviceFactory;

    @Before
    private void setUp(){
    serviceFactory = Mockito.mockStatic(ServiceFactory.class);
    Mockito.when(ServiceFactory.getResource(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(resource);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "resource", resource);
    }
}
```

here we are not able to mock getResource(String env),

Dependencies we are using for mockito:

```
 testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '3.4.4'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '3.4.4'
```

can someone suggest, how can we do this?

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito

Comment: @tgdavies : thanks for commenting, this is calling actual method which gives some internal code related exception, i dont want to call actual method

Comment: To my eyes, the way you are creating and initialising `TestedClass` seems "wrong".  Of course I have no clue about your system and I am guessing you are using Spring, as such, I would use a Configuration class to create instances of `Resource`  and then use constructor injection.  This will make testing of `TestedClass` simpler as it would no long have to deal with state resources.  `Resource`s can then be tested in isolation.

Comment: Make `ServiceFactory` a spring component (or wrap it in a Spring component) and inject it into TestedClass  so that you don't need to mock any static methods.

Comment: @tgdavies, i tried this but its not working

Comment: @Gavin, thanks but did not get how exactly can we do this? i tried creating configuration class where i mocked resource, but no luck

Comment: Without seeing what you did, or knowing how it isn't working, I can't provide any further advice.